# Separate package.json for angular e2e tests?

Tags: angular, jasmine, jestjs, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I am using Angular 8 in my project. Is it possible to have a separate `package.json` file for e2e tests? I am using `jest` for unit testing and `protractor+jasmine` for e2e. Because of this, I can't completely remove `jasmine` from my `package.json`. And, therefore, I often have problems with typings

What I want to get:

1. when i am in the `.spec` file that is inside main project
   `expect(someFuncCall()).toMatchSnapshot()` should works correct and `jasmine` should not work
2. when i am in the `.spec` file that is inside e2e folder
   `toMatchSnapshot()` should give an error and `jest` should not work

Of course, all IDE intellisense for tests should differ depends on project type: e2e/main

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled on this old question when looking for the same thing.

In our project, we use jest for normal component testing and protractor + jasmine for e2e tests. This is done with a separate `package.json` for the e2e tests.

- In the `/e2e` folder, manually add a `package.json` file with your desired dependencies.
- in there you can run `npm i` as usual (creates a `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` in there)
- the `tsconfig.e2e.json` file we use for this looks as follows:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/e2e",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
  },
  "exclude": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

I didn't want to clutter this post with too much stuff. If anything is missing, I'll be happy to post other infos (package.json, protractor.conf, etc.).

Comment: I would be grateful if you add all related informations, mainly the package.json  (I'm looking for a similar solution with Cypress )